# Excluding an XCTestCase subclass from running

Tags: xcode, xctest

I have several tests that I'd like to apply to multiple test cases. The logical thing seems to be to put those test cases in a shared superclass and have the "real" test cases extend it.

However, XCode's test runner insists on trying to run the superclass as well as the subclasses. I had hoped that it was depending on some naming convention (cf. some JUnit scenarios) but it looks like it blindly discovers and runs any and all `XCTestCase` subclasses. Is there any way to limit/exclude what the test runner discovers?